# Slow graphics on external monitor with Ubuntu 12.10 on Macbook Pro 8,3?

Tags: 12.10, macbook-pro

I have a 17-in Macbook Pro, running Snowleopard and Ubuntu 12.10. Ubuntu runs fine, except when I connect it to and external monitor. It exhibits a considerable lag in graphics acceleration. i.e. when minimizing windows using (`super key` / `command`  + `w`);

Relevant info

1. Product name by executing `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` is `MacBookPro8,3`
2. Graphic card and other hardware info by exectuting `lspci` gives `VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]`

I have searched on forums, exprimented with propritery drivers (which did not work at all) but nothing seems to enhance it. Also, I did not experience this on my Desktop. 
I am hoping someone has already found a solution.

Comment: Are you running the proprietary drivers (FGLRX) or the open-source ones (radeon)? Also, the Linux drivers for AMD are always quite inefficient. Coupled with a DE like Unity that's pretty ressource-intensive, framerates tend to drop.

Comment: I am running the open source. I tried  the proprietary one and everything breaks. I even had hard time restoring the driver.

Comment: You should try following [these instructions on installing FGLRX](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx), if you haven't done so already

Comment: This does not work. Funny thing, when I run it in a VM on mac it works fine.